# Django: form CSRF verification failed

Tags: django

This is my first Django project, however, I have a problem submitting the form.
I'm getting 'CSRF verification failed'. It's a very simple form just 2 fields(frontpage) and on submit to display the same page.

views.py

```
def newsletter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST('name') 
        email = request.POST('email')

        newsletter = Newsletter(name = name, email = email)
        newsletter.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('')
```

models.py

```
class Newsletter(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publish_date = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now, blank = True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
class NewsletterAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name','publish_date')
admin.site.register(Newsletter, NewsletterAdmin)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home_view, name = 'home'),
    path('events/', events, name = 'events'),
    path('news/', news, name = 'mainnews'),
    path('about/', about, name = 'about'),
    path('', newsletter),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

html>

```
<div>
    <form method = 'post'>
        {% csrf_token %} {{ form.as_p }} 
        <input name = 'name' type = 'text' value = "{{ newsletter.name }}">
        <input name = 'email' type = 'email' value = "{{ newsletter.email }}">
        <button type = 'submit' name = 'save'>Send</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: What does your HTML look like? You need to make sure the CSRF value is in the form.

Comment: You need to add `{% csrf_token %}` to your form.

Comment: How are you even routing to your view? `home_view` and `newsletter` appear to have the same pattern? the newsletter view would never be used that way. Also I don't see any code in newsletter view that renders the template?

Comment: home_view is frontpage. I want on submitting newsletter form the user to be redirected to the same page

Comment: `path('', home_view, name = 'home'),` and `path('', newsletter),` do you see the problem? Any url with no path would end up routing to home_view.

Comment: It's my first project, its' hard to spot the problem. How can I fix this form to work?

Comment: Which view is rendering the form? In the newsletter view I only see that it is looking for POST parameters, creating an instance and redirecting?

Answer (score 0):

Write your form like this:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" value="Submit"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: the form is submitted but in admin panel newsletters are empty

Comment: in your `models.py` it should be `models.EmailField`, not `models.CharField`

Comment: I changed the CharField to models.EmailField but still newsletters are empty

Comment: change `url path` of your `newsletter` view to something original